# Meta FAQ page outdated?

Tags: bug

I just took a look at the [meta FAQ page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/faq), and the section about reputation seems essentially outdated.

I don't recall much of a difference in privileges between the main and here (e.g. I can vote to delete on downvoted answers), so I suspect that part in the FAQ was simply not updated for a long time now.

Comment: Some of the links are still referring to this being in beta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, looks like it's missing the 15K and 20K tiers.

Could probably just replace that whole list with a link to the main FAQ - once you get past the "5 rep to post" bit, they *should* be the same.